# Create Generic IList<T> method

Tags: c#

Is it possible to create a generic IList method? Here's how I want it to be implemented:

```
List<Entity1> lstEnt1 = _myClass.GenerateListFromXml<Entity1>(@"C\test.xml");
List<Entity2> lstEnt2 = _myClass.GenerateListFromXml<Entity1>(@"C\test.xml");
```

Here's what I got so far:

```
    public List<XMLModule> RetrieveListFromXml(string appSetting, string module)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

I want to change the `XMLModule` to a generic one which I can pass in an entity.

Need help on this guys. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty simple, just use a generic T type and then decide the internal behavior.

```
public List<T> RetrieveListFromXml<T>(string appSetting, string module)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public List<T> RetrieveListFromXml<T>(string appSetting, string module)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this (I ignored your appSetting/module parameters and went based on your XML file paths used at the top)

```
    public static List<T> RetrieveListFromXml<T>(string xmlFilePath)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
        object result;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(xmlFilePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            result = serializer.Deserialize(new FileStream(xmlFilePath, FileMode.Open));
        }
        return (List<T>)result;
    }
```

Comment: interesting! i'll try this one soon. :)